# How to elegantly declare a StateFlow?

Tags: kotlin

When using StateFlow provided by Kotlin Coroutines, in order to meet the following conditions:

1. The owner can modify.
2. The caller can only read.

You often need to declare it using the following template code:

```
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(0)
val state = _state.asStateFlow()
```

This approach may feel quite redundant.

Is there a better way to declare it only once and still satisfy the above conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be supported in Kotlin 2.0 with the [explicit backing fields](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/explicit-backing-fields-re/proposals/explicit-backing-fields.md) feature:

```
val state: StateFlow<Int>
    field = MutableStateFlow(0)
```

Inside the class, the compiler will let you use `state` to directly access its backing field and will be treated as its more specific type.

You can already try it out in Kotlin 1.9 if you enable the beta of the K2 compiler by adding `kotlin.experimental.tryK2=true` to `gradle.properties`. This is not recommended for production builds.

However, this is not exactly equivalent to what you get with `asStateFlow()`, which actually wraps your MutableStateFlow in a new Flow instance that cannot be externally cast back to a MutableStateFlow. I don't know the reason `asStateFlow()` even exists when there's no `asList()` or `asSet()` for the standard mutable collections. If conventions are followed, I wouldn't expect you to have to worry about another programmer casting your types to cause problems for themselves.

Comment: Great point about `asStateFlow`. I've always wondered the same thing about Java's `Collections.unmodifiableList/Set`, which is even more useless because it doesn't remove the mutation methods from the returned type.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, I use `asStateFlow` because I have to explicitly declare `val state: StateFlow<Int> = _state` when providing StateFlow externally. Using `asStateFlow` is just a way to be lazy :p